# Creating fixed floating div in scrolling page

Tags: html, css

In this example i need the div in yellow color to stay fix and not to scroll with the page. and div in the red color to display below yellow div with some margin in between. And when the red div scrolls it should scroll under yellow div and there should be margin in between yellow and red div. please help with this.

```css
.fixspan
{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.scrollingdiv
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='fixspan'>
    <span>This should not scroll with the page.</span>
</div>
<div class='scrollingdiv'>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
</div>
```

Comment: used to this .fixspan{left:0;right:0;top:0;}

Comment: I don't understand. "And when the red div scrolls it[the yellow div] should scroll there" and "div in yellow color to stay fix" are two contradicting statements

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Please try to clear up your question, it makes no sense - by the sounds of it you want a scrolling div that doesn't scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/oXVmLW) what you are looking for?

CSS:

```
.fixspan {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
}

.scrollingdiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 88%;
}
```

I just added top, right, width and height properties. Otherwise your yellow does not know where it should "stay".

Answer (score 1):

```css
.scrollingdiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='fixspan'>
  <span>This should not scroll with the page.</span>
</div>
<div class='scrollingdiv'>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
  <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
</div>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that is that you need (your question is poor and un-understandable). The yellow div is not scrolling with the page, so is absolute positioning.

```css
.fixspan
{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.scrollingdiv
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='fixspan'>
    <span>This should not scroll with the page.</span>
</div>
<div class='scrollingdiv'>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
    <p>This is to expand content of the page</p>
</div>
```